# Highlighting invalid form inputs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on creating a form with a set of fields like username, passwords etc.... 
I want to make validation when the SUBMIT button is clicked.

I'm trying to get alert from my border color. All fields are valid my border must change into Green color If it has any errors it should change to red color.

Any one has any ideas regarding to my problem

If anyone has any suggestion??

Comment: you could try writing your own script. Or look for javascript plugins that does your needs. But what have you tried so far?

Comment: Use Javascript..its as easy as that.. ull get no ready made scripts here.... try on your own, read some books, if u have a problem post what you tried and ask whats wrong

Comment: i tried but i could not able to find one will anyone help to locate that javascript

Comment: you can use jquery form validation plugin. it's very easy and documentation is very clear. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: I know about all the basic stuff about validating. i tried and succeeded in normal validating by image  or messages near input box .. but i was not able to validate by border of form

Comment: people please stop pushing people to w3schools. The site is out dated, inaccurate and full of bugs (http://w3fools.com/). w3.org is the source of information to get it right.

Comment: JAVASCRIPT JAVASCRIPT JAVASCRIPT :%. You can also use HTML5 with the required attribute <input required="required" ... /> !

Comment: Am not sure if javascript is the best for validation.. what if the browser has disable jvavascript ??? .. Would you like a pure PHP solution ?

Comment: @VivekDragon, the best option for you is to go for php validation for your own. You can use pregmatch and in-built validations like [email validation] (http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php).
You can get lazy and use some jquery plugins as well

Comment: What do you want to get exatly? I understand it like usually there will be no border on a form, but once submit clicked - it should get red border if it is not valid or green if valid. Is that correct?

Comment: Use jQuery validation docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation it's not about being lazy as @Sidath states but it enables good user experience, which is an essential part of a good webform. BUT don't forget to check the input in the PHP script for malicious code (script injections, sql injections) before working with it!

Answer (score 18):

You can use jquery plugin.... here you are. [JQuery Form validation custom example](http://jsfiddle.net/coder2/Kzy2J/12/)

Comment: I agree with Ryan. The user clearly does not have the knowledge to write it him/herself. +1

Comment: This example has the excact coding you're looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Use jQuery validation plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

In this plugin, you have to define validation rules for the field. You can also set the error messages for given field for given validation rule.

This plugin adds classes to valid and invalid field.

You have to give the css for that class.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".my_form").validate({
                    rules:{  // validation rules
                            email_address: {
                                required:true,
                                email: true
                            },
                            password:{
                                minlength: 6
                            },
                            confirm_password: {
                                         equalTo:"#password"
                            }
                    },
                    messages: {
                        email_address: {
                           required: "Please enter email address",
                           email: "Please enter valid email address",
                       },
                       /*
                          likewise you can define messages for different field 
                          for different rule.
                       */
                    }
                    errorClass: "signup_error",  
                     /*This is error class that will be applied to 
                      invalid element. Use this class to style border. 
                      You can give any class name.*/
                });
      });
```

Once you click on submit button, and field is invalid, the plugin adds class to the element that you have specified as `errorClass`, and when you enter valid value in the field, the plugin will remove this class and will add `'valid'` class by default.

You can use these two classes to style valid and invalid element using simple element.

```
.valid {
   border-color:"green"
}

.signup_error {
  border-color:"red"
}
```

Hope this resolves your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Js i the way to go. You can find some really good validators for jQuery should you google for it.

To custom build a simple validator I would go like this

```
<form class="validator">
  <input type="text" name="my-input-1" data-validator="integer"/>
  <input type="text" name="my-input-2" data-validator="email"/>
  ....
</form>

<script>
   $("form.validator").submit(evt, function() {
      var errors = 0;
      $(this).find('[data-validator]').each(function(e, i) {
         var value = $(this).value;
         switch($(this).data('validator')) {
            case 'integer':
               if (!(parseFloat(value) == parseInt(value)) && !isNaN(value)) {
                  $(this).css({'border-color': '#FF0000'});
                  errors++;
               } else
                  $(this).css({'border-color': '#000000'});
               break;
            case 'email':
               if (..... // regex validate email ...) {
                  $(this).css({'border-color': '#FF0000'});
                  errors++;
               } else
                  $(this).css({'border-color': '#000000'});
               break;
         }
      });
      if (errors > 0) {
         // If you want to prevent default event execution no matter what
         evt.preventDefault();
         // If you want you other attached events to NOT run
         evt.stopPropagation();
         // signal failure
         return false;
      }

      // All is well, go on
      return true;
   });
</script>
```

of course it's always good practice to build functions for every validator and even better to wrap the whole thing in a jQuery widget (I would suggest using jQuery Widget Factory) which would allow you to enhance it in the future and keep you flexible to changes

Answer (score 2):

You can use DOJO library to validate form fields. It's easy to implement.

Given below is the tutorial to implement dojo

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/validation/

and this is the working example you can see...

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/validation/demo/dijitcheck.html

Answer (score 1):

I made a validation library just for general javascript purposes. It is even unit tested! You can override whatever you want fairly easily as well: https://github.com/parris/iz

As far as highlighting invalid fields you can just change the style of that field or add a class. The example below just changes the background color of the input and adds a message.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/soparrissays/4BrNu/1/

```
$(function() {
    var message = $("#message"),
        field = $("#field");
    $("#the-form").submit(function(event) {
        if (iz(field.val()).alphaNumeric().not().email().valid){
            message.text("Yay! AlphaNumeric and not an email address");
            field.attr("style","background:green;");
        } else {
            message.text("OH no :(, it must be alphanumeric and not an email address");
            field.attr("style","background:red;");
        }
        return false;
    });
});​
```

The validator is called iz. It simply lets you chain validations together and it will tell you if everything passed or if you check the "errors" object it'll give you more specifics. Beyond that you can specify your own error messages. Check the docs on github.

What is happening here is we are setting a click handler for the submit event once the page is ready. `return false;` at the bottom of the submit callback prevents the form from submitting. If you `return true;` the form will continue on. Instead of return false you could also `event.preventDefault();` but I prefer the return syntax for consistency. In the real world with multiple form elements you may do something like this (psuedo code):

```
var passed = true;
if (check field 1 is false)
    ...
if (check field 2 is false)
    ...
if (check field n is false)
    passed = false
    style and add message

if passed
    return true
else
    return false
```

The if statement checks the validation rules and makes changes to the DOM accordingly. By doing it in this way you are able to give a complete list of all passed and failed fields with a full description of what is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [this plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) in the past, makes implementation very easy and has good documentation and examples.

Answer (score 1):

My advice use jQuery

to try first create multiple inputs and give them a class

html:

```
<input type="text" class="validate" value="asdf" />
<input type="text" class="validate" value="1234" />
<input type="text" class="validate" value="asd123" />
<input type="text" class="validate" value="£#$&" />
<input type="text" class="validate" value="  " />
```

then use the code below to see how it works

jQuery:

```
// Validate Function
function validate(element) {
    var obj = $(element);
    if (obj.val().trim() != "") {
        // Not empty
        if (!/^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]{1,10}$/.test(obj.val())) {
            // Invalid
            obj.css('border-color', '#FAC3C3');
            if (!obj.next().hasClass('error'))
            { obj.after('<span class="error">Please use letters or numbers only and not more than 10 characters!</span>'); }
            else
            { obj.next().text('Please use letters or numbers only and not more than 10 characters!'); }
        } else {
            // Valid
            obj.css('border-color', 'lightgreen');
            if (obj.next().hasClass('error'))
            { obj.next().remove(); }
        }
    } else {
        // Empty
        obj.css('border-color', '#FAC3C3');
        if (obj.next().hasClass('error'))
        { obj.next().text('This field cannot be empty!'); }
        else
        { obj.after('<span class="error error-keyup-1">This field cannot be empty!</span>'); }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Each
    $('.validate').each(function() {
        // Validate
        validate(this);
        // Key up
        $(this).keyup(function() {
            // Validate
            validate(this);
        });
    });
});
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/nh2Ja/

Answer (score 1):

A server side validation example of your need. You may try it out.

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

$green = "border: 3px solid green";
$red="border: 3px solid red";
$nothing="";

$color = array ("text1"=>$nothing , "text2"=>$nothing) ;


if ( $_POST['submit'] ) {

    if($_POST['text1']) {
        $color['text1'] = $green;       
    }

    else $color['text1'] = $red;

    if($_POST['text2'] ) {
        $color['text2'] = $green;
    }

    else $color['text2'] = $red;
}



?>


<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="text1" style="<?php echo $color ['text1']?>" value="<?php echo $_POST['text1']?>">
    <input type="text" name="text2" style="<?php echo $color ['text2']?>" value="<?php echo $_POST['text2']?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">


</form>
```

---

### Note

1. Always **sanitize** user input.
2. error_reporting off is not a good practice at all. I did it as this is not a code of production environment.
3. Check before trying to access in the post array using isset or something similar function like this.
4. Always check if a variable exist before using.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
        // Check all of them 
        if( $.trim($("#file").val()) == ""){
            $("#file").css("border","1px solid #ff5555");
        }else{
            $("#file").css("border","1px solid #cccccc");
            if( $.trim($("#showboxResimBaslik").val()) == ""){
                $("#showboxResimBaslik").css("border","1px solid #ff5555");
            }else{
                $("#showboxResimBaslik").css("border","1px solid #cccccc");
                if( $.trim($("#showboxResimEtiket").val()) == ""){
                    $("#showboxResimEtiket").css("border","1px solid #ff5555");
                }else{  
                    if($.trim($("#showboxResimSehir").val()) == ""){
                        $("#showboxResimSehir").css("border","1px solid #ff5555");
                    }else{
                        $("#showboxResimSehir").css("border","1px solid #cccccc");
                        $("#resimYukleForm").removeAttr("onSubmit");
                        $('#resimYukleForm').bind('submit', form_submit);
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

probably the easiest way is to use this javascript: 
http://livevalidation.com/examples#exampleComposite

I think it suits your description the best.

Answer (score 0):

check below link, here i have only checked for empty fields and if the fields are empty then changed input fields id which will change input field border color.
http://jsfiddle.net/techprasad/jBG7L/2/

I have used

```
$("#myb").click(function(){
```

that is on button click event but you can use submit event.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would say is short precise and concise way to do this in jQuery.

HTML:

```
<form id="myform" name="form"  action="http://www.google.com">
                    <div class="line"><label>Your Username</label><input class="req" type="text" /></div>
                    <div class="line"><label>Your Password</label><input class="req" type="password" /></div>
                    <div class="line"><label>Your Website</label><input class="req" type="text" /></div>
                    <div class="line"><label>Your Message</label><textarea  class="req"></textarea></div>
                    <div class="line"><input type="submit" id="sub"></submit>

                </form>
```

CSS:

```
.line{padding-top:10px;}
        .inline input{padding-left: 20px;}
        label{float:left;width:120px;}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
            function validateform() {
                var valid = true;
                $(".req").css("border","1px solid green");
                $(".req").each(function() {
                    if($(this).val() == "" ||  $(this).val().replace(/\s/g, '').length == 0) {
                        $(this).css("border","1px solid red");
                        valid = false;
                    }
                });
                return valid;
                }

                $("#sub").click(function() {
                $('#myform').submit(validateform);
                    $('#myform').submit();
                });

        });
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/FhNv7/)

Answer (score 0):

Well hi, you can use html5 "required" and "pattern" in your form's fields.
You'll get red border if it's wrong and green if it's right.
You can even style the :valid and :invalid entry fields if the colors aren't which you wanted.
I've never tested it but why not, it's better than nothing ;)

[html5 solution](http://www.alsacreations.com/tuto/lire/1392-formulaire-html5-placeholder-required-pattern.html)

Answer (score -1):

Firs Learn javascript, if you have some basic knowledge of js and need to know the logic, go on read..
First you need an event handler to run a function on form submit
Easiest way is (though there are better ways)

```
<form action="som.php" onsubmit="functionName()">
```

form here

```
</form>
```

This will trigger the function called functionname.
In function name function access the input fields and validate using regular expressions

```
function functionName()
{
//verification code
if(verified)
{
//code to change border to green
}


}
```

You need to get the input fields and validate them. If you don't know how to do that, get a few Javascript books
**If you need to validate as soon as value is typed use the on onchange event on input fields**